# Can Armored Cable and Nonmetallic sheathed cable be used together?

Tags: electrical

Can metal jacket wiring, that uses the metal jacket as a ground, be used with conventional Romex wiring?

Comment: Clarify "used with". Are you sure it's using the jacket *as* the ground and not ground*ing* the jacket?

Comment: "Greenfield" usually refers to liquidtight flexible metal conduit (LFMC), not AC or MC.  Could you clarify your question please?

Comment: My apologies. BX Armored Cable is more accurate. It is a 1930's house and I believe that the armored jacket is used as ground. I want to add additional lighting using Romex wiring and wonder if there are regulations or other issues that would prevent me from doing this.

Answer (score 1):

If both wiring methods are allowed in your area then both can be used together.

As always, proper terminations and grounding must be considered.

Also be very careful. Even though you have AC cable, the older stuff, like what you have, is rarely an accepted or safe grounding path. These circuits cannot be extended.

Answer (score -1):

The answer for these sort of questions is generally, "Ask your permitting authority". It depends on the regulations in your area.

Comment: This is certainly not one of those questions @Eric Gunnerson. This is a straight forward code/common practice question, as long as both wiring methods are approved.